# adding column dynically and then converting it in hql

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a pojo consist of the following fields

```
public class tooks 
{

    private String bbb;
    private DateTime ccc;
    private String ddd;
    private boolean eee = true;

    }
```

Now I have the following sql ..

```
    SELECT distinct u.bbb, 'Not Defined' Access_Type, u.ccc, u.ddd 
        FROM IOA_tooks u where u.eee='N' order by u.aaa
```

Now as you can see the column Access_Type is created in the query itself and there is no property in pojo above. Please suggest how to convert this sql into hql and what changes need to be done in pojo

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. An HQL query can only result in Hibernate-mapped objects, and I see no objects in your snippet that could be mapped to the SQL statement you have posted. Can you post the entity object that you intend to map the results of this query to?

Comment: @entity object , means the hbm mapping

Comment: i was simply looking to convert  this sql into hql that all but one column is not defined my pojo

Comment: Is it your intention to include u.bbb twice in the results (is the second one supposed to map to something else)? Do you *need* to have Access_Type in the result set, since you already know it is "Not Defined"?

Comment: sorry for the typo updated the post  u.bbb will be once yeah I want to have access_type in the result set once solution i was thinking to add in the corresponding pojo named tooks along with getters and setters please advise

Comment: and if i add access type then I don't define in hbm mapping will it create conflict please advise

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (note that if you want to map "Y"/"N" to a Boolean type you'd have to create a custom data type; this example will stick to a String):

```
public class tooks {
    private String bbb;
    private DateTime ccc;
    private transient String accessType = "Not Defined";
    private String ddd;
    private String eee = "Y";
}
```

I can't really tell what you are going for, you have provided no other information, so I can only assume that you always want accessType to be "Not Defined". It's not an actual column in the database and therefore logically doesn't map to any field in an object. Therefore, just map bbb, ccc, ddd, and eee in your mapping file / annotations, and do not map accessType as it's unrelated to the database.

Hibernate will ignore transient fields in field mapping. If you're using method mapping (getters/setters) you should mark getAccessType and setAccessType with JPA's @Transient annotation, and Hibernate will ignore them.

Then the HQL is pretty much exactly the same as the SQL:

```
List<took> tooks = (List<took>)session.createQuery("select distinct t from took t where t.eee = 'N' order by t.aaa asc").list();
```

Every object in your result will have accessType == "Not Defined", but note that's not because it was selected from the database (since it's not mapped), it's just the value that was initialized in the Java object, which seems to be the end result you were going for.